# read multiple lines from text file and added it to registry

Tags: powershell

Very very new to PowerShell

First off all I'd like to give the scenario what I'm trying to do.

We have a SharePoint site and users can add their OneNote books to this SharePoint site. The URL's to the SharePoint site is now changing. So I'm exporting the registry entries to a text file, change the part of the path to the new one, and add the new URL's to the registry.
The problem I'm having is when I export the URL's (because of the way I'm exporting for sure) the text file has a string called "Value" and the URL's are under it.

So the first question is how do I write the values to a text file where only the values get written (in this case the URL's) 
And second question is how do I write these changed values back to the registry? 
Every URL is a new "string" and the names start with 1, 2, 3 and so on.

Thank you everyone for their time in advance.

```
# Create a new folder if not exist file
$Folder = "C:\backup"
if(-not(Test-Path $Folder)){
New-Item -Path $Folder -ItemType Directory
}

# Start Logging
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\backup\onenote.log"

#Set Variables

$OneNoteBooks = "C:\backup\onenotenotebooks.txt"
$NewPath = '//newpath.com/'


# Delete the existing file if exists
If (Test-Path $OneNoteBooks){Remove-Item $OneNoteBooks}

# Create a new text file
New-Item -Path $OneNoteBooks -ItemType File

# Exporting OneNote SharePoint Notebooks and Correcting them to the new URL
Write-Host "Exporting OneNote SharePoint Notebooks and Correcting them to the new URL"

Push-Location
Set-Location 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Onenote\opennotebooks' 

Get-Item . | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property | ForEach-Object {

New-Object PSobject -Property @{"property"=$_;

"Value" = (Get-ItemProperty -Path . -Name $_).$_}} | Format-Table Value -AutoSize |     Out-File $OneNoteBooks

Pop-Location

$ReplaceURL = Get-Content -Path $OneNoteBooks
ForEach-Object{
$ReplaceURL -replace "`//.*?(`/)", $NewPath | Out-File $OneNoteBooks

}


# Add Changed URL's to the registry

ForEach-Object {
New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion -Name     PowerShellPath -PropertyType String -Value $PSHome


# Stop Logging
Stop-Transcript
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where to start? How about with the fact that in your ForEach loop you create an object with two properties, and then use Format-Table (alias FT used), and select one of the two properties making the whole object pointless... instead just get and output the value that you want.

```
Get-Item . | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty -Path . -Name $_).$_} | Out-File $OneNoteBooks
```

Or better yet, use the built in functions of the Item from your Get-Item to get and set your values in a ForEach loop. Try this out...

```
# Create a new folder if not exist file
$Folder = "C:\backup"
if(-not(Test-Path $Folder)){
New-Item -Path $Folder -ItemType Directory
}

# Start Logging
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\backup\onenote.log"

#Set Variables

$OneNoteBooks = "C:\backup\onenotenotebooks.txt"
$NewPath = '//newpath.com/'
$OldPath = '//oldpath.com/'
$SitesChangingMask = "$([regex]::escape("$oldpath"))(nibremv|finance|sites/procurement|Comm|Departments/NITAS|ro|nitd|cnibr|communities/sig)/?"

# Delete the existing file if exists
If (Test-Path $OneNoteBooks){Remove-Item $OneNoteBooks}

# Create a new text file
New-Item -Path $OneNoteBooks -ItemType File

# Exporting OneNote SharePoint Notebooks and Correcting them to the new URL
"Exporting OneNote SharePoint Notebooks and Correcting them to the new URL"

Push-Location
Set-Location 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Onenote\opennotebooks' 

$OneNoteReg = Get-Item . 
$OneNoteReg.Property | ForEach-Object {
    $CurrentValue = $OneNoteReg.GetValue($_)
    $NewValue = if($CurrentValue.ToString() -match $SitesChangingMask){$CurrentValue.ToString() -replace "$OldPath", $NewPath}else{$CurrentValue.ToString()}
    Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Onenote\opennotebooks' -Name $_ -Value $NewValue
    [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
        "Value Name"=$_
        "Original Value"=$CurrentValue
        "Updated Value"=$NewValue
    }
} | FT -AutoSize | Out-File $OneNoteBooks

Pop-Location

# Stop Logging
Stop-Transcript
```

I also changed your RegEx pattern for your replace since the old one didn't seem right. For example, in `HTTP://www.microsoft.com/powershell` it would update that string to read `http://www.microsoft.com//newsite.com/powershell` and I don't think that was your intention.

Comment: Hi TheMadTechnician. Not to make you any more mad :)  but the code doesn't work. I get access denied error when I try it. I tried adding a value directly thru the registry and powershell and i was able to. So I think along the code somewhere something is missing? The part where I was changing the URL was working on my code. I really like your idea of the old value and the newvalue part. I would love to have that to work but at the end I have to import those to the registry. Would you be able to help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Updated and tested. This should work for you now. I changed .SetValue() to use Set-ItemProperty instead.

Comment: Hi TheMad. Would you be able to tell me how to modify this script so that it only changes if it sees "oldpath.path.intra"http://oldpath.path.intra/departments/finance"

Comment: That should do it. Added $OldPath variable, and changed the -Replace to use that.

Comment: That works like a charm. Except for 1 problem that I forgot to mention. Only the following sites are changing from the oldpath to the new. So the script needs to change only if it see's these paths. You have no idea how much I appreciate your help.
http://oldpath.com/nibremv 
http://oldpath.com/finance
http://oldpath.com/sites/procurement/
http://oldpath.com/Comm
http://oldpath.com/Departments/NITAS/
http://oldpath.com/ro/
http://oldpath.com/nitd
http://oldpath.com/cnibr
http://oldpath.com/communities/sig

Comment: Thank you again once more. But when I ran the script, it changed the values to the names in registry which in this case is 
1 -2 - 3- 4- etc.

Comment: Wow, sorry, should have gotten more caffeen in me first. Updated answer. The change was in the If() statement. Changed $_ to $CurrentValue.ToString(). $_ references the property name that it's looping through. Not sure why I didn't catch that before.

Comment: haha. No worries. I swear if you said "Yes" I'd send you a gift card for starbucks .:))
So I changed the if statement like you suggested. Now it leaves everything else that doesn't need to be changed and replaces the values with names for the ones that needs to be changed. :) Sorry for being a pain.

Comment: Your `$NewValue=` line looks like the one above? Sounds like you missed a $_. I did update the answer before, what you're describing should be fixed with what I have up there.

Comment: Yes I did miss that part. But now it doesn't change any of the old paths to the new ones. :(

Comment: I created the reg key with 3 values "//oldpath.com/finance","//oldpath.com", and "//oldpath.com/tacotruck" and ran the script in my answer. It updated the first value to "//newpath.com/finance" and left the other two. Is that not the desired result?

Comment: hehehe.. Now I guess it's my time to put some caffeine in my body. I didn't change the new and old path to match my registry. hahaa..
it works like a charm. I can't tell you how much I appreciate this. My coffee offer still stands if you want to contact me and give me your starbucks card and I will add to it :)) 
THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: Hi Mad unfortunately it's me again. The script is changing oldpat.com/itprojects to newpath.com/itprojects even tho it's not in the list. I tried with other stuff and it works as its supposed to but for some reason it changes ITProjects too. :(

Comment: my fault, I wasn't specific enough with the RegEx. I have updated the answer with a better RegEx that should fix the problem.

Comment: You are my awesome :) Wish I could get lessons from you. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

When saving data to a file, skip using the `Format` commands.  You could use a CSV file here instead:

```
Get-Item . | Select-Object -Exp Property | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{"Property"=$_;"Value"=(Get-ItemProperty . -Name $_).$_}} |
Export-Csv $OneNoteBooks
```

Modify the file, then re-read it like so:

```
$props = Import-Csv $OneNoteBooks
```

Then you can access the property names and values like so:

```
$props.Property[0]
$props.Value[0]
..
```

Of course, you don't really need to go to a file to modify the values.  You could do it in memory:

```
$props = Get-Item . | Select-Object -Exp Property | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{"Property"=$_;"Value"=(Get-ItemProperty . -Name $_).$_}}

$props = $props | Foreach {$_.Value = $_.Value -replace 'pattern','replacement'}
```

If you would prefer to create a .reg file that you can then import try this:

```
"Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`n" > c:\onenotebooks.reg
"[$($pwd.ProviderPath)]" >> c:\onenotebooks.reg
Get-Item . | Select-Object -Exp Property | 
    ForEach-Object { "`"$_`"=`"$((Get-ItemProperty . -Name $_).$_)`"" } >> c:\onenotebooks.reg
```

Comment: Hi Keith. Thanks for your response. This really did help a lot. Although I'd rather stick with a text file, I can always do CSV file if that is my only option. However. The code you provided doesn't work. It doesn't even convert it to CSV. Is it possible to just have something like "1 http://test.com/test/test/test. 2 http://test.com/test/test/test" and so on each line depending on how many lines of URL's are there? I'm assuming that would be easier to just import it to the registry. Which I also need help with. Thanks again.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you on? I tested this on V4 and it creates the csv correctly and imports it back in correctly.

Comment: See the updated answer for creating a .reg file that you can import with reg.exe.

Comment: I guess that explains it. Our company is still on Version 3. I appreciate your help and effort.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in this line of code.

```
"Value" = (Get-ItemProperty -Path . -Name $_).$_}} | Format-Table Value -AutoSize | Out-File $OneNoteBooks
```

I'd suggest removing the format-table.  If its not showing you everything then try this:

```
"Value" = (Get-ItemProperty -Path . -Name $_).$_}} | Foreach-Object {$_.Value} | Out-File $OneNoteBooks
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Thank you. But now how do I import each line to the registry with names being 1, 2, 3, and so on depending on how many lines of URL's are there? Thanks in advance.